# retrieving one string value from cursor

Tags: android

i have one table in my android project with 3 columns , i just want to get specific value from one column (String value) in my Main activity from the table..
i used this code but it returns the whole list and i just want one value depending on a condition

public List  getAlltableList () {

```
    List <AI_TABLE> tableArrayList = new ArrayList <AI_TABLE>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + AI_TABLE;

    Log.d (TAG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery (selectQuery, null);


    // looping through all rows and adding to list
```

if (!c.isAfterLast())

```
   c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){

            AI_TABLE table = new AI_TABLE();

            table.ID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ID));

            table.Q = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Q));

            table.Q_ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Q_ID));

            table.A = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(A));

            // adding to Students list

            tableArrayList.add(table);

        c.moveToNext();

        }

    return tableArrayList;
}
```

Comment: you have written query which will return you all data from table , modify your query according to your need

Comment: what should i use instead of list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your string query by adding the Where condition like so

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT some_column FROM " + AI_TABLE + " WHERE some_field = ?" ;
```

Then just add a selection argument when you query the DB

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery (selectQuery, new String[] {"SOME_VALUE"} );
```

This will only return some_column to the cursor where some_field equals "SOME_VALUE"

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: It means that the cursor has not moved yet. You need to atleast set it to the first row by saying,   c.moveToFirst();   After this you can access its row. If you have done that just get the value by saying c.getString(0); This will get the first column. Since you only have one column in the query, its all you can access.

Comment: ok , man please just help with this.. iwill give you the method , can you rewrite again the way you know it?

Comment: because ihave anull value returning now

Comment: maaaaaan thank you it worked:) , it just returns the value 5 times , and with square brackets , what should i do??

Comment: Its possible that you have 5 records with the same value in that column. If you change your query from SELECT some_column     to   SELECT DISTINCT some_column   it will only return one.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a projection on the query selecting just the column you want something in the like of `'SELECT column_name from'  + AI_TABLE` and then just get the column with index 0 from the cursor